# Introduction to the sound desing

Tags: recommendations, education, sound-design

Could some one post a link where one can find an introduction to the sound desing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.soundeffectsbible.com/ Book is excellent choice.

Answer (score 1):

Sound Design by David Sonnenschein is also a good choice: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iGt70tqyWGwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=sound+design&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vZ7PT7-BHOrD0QX-ytHJCw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=sound%20design&f=false

Comment: I second this!!

Answer (score 1):

Designing sound is a good site with lots of interesting articles and videos:-

http://designingsound.org/